# JavaScript querySelector versions of Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to move away from JQuery.

I have a div called 'clientProfiles'

```
<div class="paperlist" data-role='listview' data-inset='true' data-split-icon='delete' id='clientProfiles'></div>
```

my application will fill the 'div' with buttons like so.

```
function getClientHtml(device) {

                var html = "";
                html += '<div data-name="' + device.Name + '" data-id="' + device.Id + '"data-app="' + device.AppName + '" style="border-radius: 2px; border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.158)" class="clientProfile listItem">';
                html += '<img style="float-left; width:3%;" src="' + deviceNameImage(device.Name) + '"/>';
                html += '<div class="listItemBody">';
                html += '<h3 class="listItemBodyText">' + device.Name + ' - ' + device.AppName + '</h3>';
                html += '</div>';
                html += '<i class="md-icon btnDeleteProfile" data-index="0">close</i>';
                html += '</div>';
                html += '<br />';
                return html;
            };
```

The html after a button has been added by a user looks like this:

```
<div class="paperlist" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-split-icon="delete" id="clientProfiles">
<div data-name="Xbox One" data-id="mcX7xXZksA1fJooKY2SRS5soNbFgM4lQurFx3bxr2s" data-app="Theater" style="border-radius: 2px; border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.158)" class="clientProfile listItem">
<img style="float-left; width:3%;" src="../images/devices/xboxone.png"><div class="listItemBody"><h3 class="listItemBodyText">XBLAHBLAHNAME</h3>
</div>
<i class="md-icon btnDeleteProfile" data-index="0">close</i>
</div>
<br>
</div>
```

These dynamically created buttons can be removed from the page by clicking an icon  inside the main button labeled with a with a class called '.btnDeleteProfile'.

When I wanted to add a click event to my 'btnDeleteProfile' in JQuery I could use this:

```
 $('#clientProfiles', page).on('click', '.btnDeleteProfile', function () {});
```

But now that I am not using JQuery, I'm having an issue targeting the '.btnDeleteProfile'.

document.querySelector('.btnDeleteProfile').addEventListener('click', function() {});

However MDN says that querySelector will only find the first instance of this, and there could very well be a ton of these buttons created all with different profile info attached.

the query Selector can't find the 'btnDeleteProfile'.

The error I am experiencing is 'can't add click event to null.

Comment: Search stackoverflow for "event delegation without jquery".  `on()` is not a vanilla javascript method.

Comment: Sorry right, I meant addEventListeners. Still I can't target the icon.

Comment: Right, because it doesn't exist.  Which is why you were using the delegate form of bindings in jQuery.

Comment: Add event listeners when the button is created. Not before... I think I understand.

Comment: @user2224583 you have to call `querySelector` again after you added the dynamic html code.

Comment: No, you do not **have** to do that, provided the event bubbles.  That's why event delegation exists.  http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/  This same logic can be done in vanilla javascript, with some work.

Comment: Check out `querySelectorAll` method for getting all document's elements that match the selector.

Comment: The querySelectorAll might be okay if the buttons exist, but I think I have to wire the click events during the creation of the button. Reading the 'event-delegation' article quickly I can see that there is no event bubble happening in the app.

Comment: I am not sure what page refers to in your example, and if it is a `document`, but apart from that, I think using `document.querySelectorAll('#clientProfiles .btnDeleteProfile').addEventListener('click', function() {});` could work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [applying an event handler to newly created objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34032123/applying-an-event-handler-to-newly-created-objects)

Comment: @user2224583 I'm not sure where you got `I can see that there is no event bubble happening in the app` from that article.  The entire ability for delegates to work relies on events bubbling.  And indeed, the `click` event does bubble.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

> [Event​.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target): The target property of the Event interface is a reference to the object that dispatched the event.

The snippet:

```js
function getClientHtml(device) {

    var html = "";
    html += '<div data-name="' + device.Name + '" data-id="' + device.Id + '"data-app="' + device.AppName + '" style="border-radius: 2px; border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.158)" class="clientProfile listItem">';
    html += '<img style="float-left; width:3%;" src="../images/devices/xboxone.png"/>';
    html += '<div class="listItemBody">';
    html += '<h3 class="listItemBodyText">' + device.Name + ' - ' + device.AppName + '</h3>';
    html += '</div>';
    html += '<i class="md-icon btnDeleteProfile" data-index="0">close</i>';
    html += '</div>';
    html += '<br />';
    return html;
}

 var clientProfiles = document.querySelector('#clientProfiles');

clientProfiles.innerHTML += getClientHtml({Name: 'Xbox One', id: "mcX7xXZksA1fJooKY2SRS5soNbFgM4lQurFx3bxr2s", AppName: 'Theater'});
clientProfiles.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target.classList.contains('btnDeleteProfile')) {
        e.target.closest('div').remove();
        console.log('Do it');
    }
})
```

```html
<div class="paperlist" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-split-icon="delete" id="clientProfiles">
    <div data-name="Xbox One" data-id="mcX7xXZksA1fJooKY2SRS5soNbFgM4lQurFx3bxr2s" data-app="Theater" style="border-radius: 2px; border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.158)" class="clientProfile listItem">
        <img style="float-left; width:3%;" src="../images/devices/xboxone.png"><div class="listItemBody"><h3 class="listItemBodyText">XBLAHBLAHNAME</h3>
    </div>
        <i class="md-icon btnDeleteProfile" data-index="0">close</i>
    </div>
    <br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use event delegation. With event delegation, you add an event handler to an element that will exist prior to the dynamic content being added. All events that occur to dynamically added elements will bubble up the DOM to the existing element that you've attached your handler to. Your event handler will then need to inspect the event to know if it should do what it should do.

In my simple example, I've attached a delegated handler to `#list`. It waits for an element with the `.close` class to be clicked, issuing a `click` event, to remove the `li` from the list.

```js
var addItemToList = function addItemToList( listNode, text ) {
  
  var li          = document.createElement( 'li' );
  var spanClose   = document.createElement( 'span' );
  var spanNothing = document.createElement( 'span' );
  
  li.textContent = text;

  spanClose.className = 'close';
  spanClose.innerHTML = '⨯';

  spanNothing.className = 'nothing';
  spanNothing.innerHTML = '★';

  li.appendChild( spanClose )
  li.appendChild( spanNothing );
  listNode.appendChild( li );

};

var getRandomText = function getRandomText() {
  return randomText[ Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) ];
};

var removeListItem = function removeListItem( e ) {

  // e.target = <span>
  if ( e.target.classList.contains( 'close' ) ) {
  
    var li = e.target.parentNode; 
    var ul = li.parentNode;

    ul.removeChild( li );

  }

}

var addToListBtn = document.querySelector( 'button' );
var theList      = document.querySelector( '#list' );
var randomText   = [ 'Hello!', 'Huh?', 'Okay' ];

addToListBtn.addEventListener( 'click', function ( e ) {
  addItemToList( theList, getRandomText() );
} );

theList.addEventListener( 'click', removeListItem );
```

```css
li {
  line-height: 1.5;
}

li span {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  padding: 0.25rem 0.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<button>Add to List</button>

<ul id="list"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could generalize this a bit, by making your own delegate event listener logic.

- Bind the event listener to the parent
- When the event happens, find all the children of the parent that match the child selector
- If the element the event originated from is in that child list, apply the event callback to it.

```js
Element.prototype.addDelegateEventListener = function (eventType, childSelector, callback) {
  var parentElement = this;
  
  parentElement.addEventListener(eventType, function(event){
    var children = [...parentElement.querySelectorAll(childSelector)];
    
    if (children.includes(event.target)) {
      callback.apply(event.target, arguments);
    }
  });
};


document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].addEventListener('click', function(){
  document.querySelector('#parent').innerHTML += `<div class="clickMe" data-created-on="${Date.now()}">Click Me</div>`;
});

document.getElementById('parent').addDelegateEventListener( 'click', '.clickMe', function(e){
  console.log(this);
  console.log(e.target);
});
```

```html
<button>Add Element</button>
<div id="parent">
  <div>No Match</div>
  <div>
    <div class="clickMe">Indirect Child</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, if you're just wanting to get that code to work, gaetanoM's answer is great.

However, it seems like the heart of your question is how to target *all* of the delete buttons in order to attach the function. So for future reference you can use `querySelectorAll` and a `forEach` like MDN shows here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll#Accessing_the_matches

```
// use querySelectorAll to get a node list of the elements, similar to how you would get a jQuery object in jQuery
var deleteButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".btnDeleteProfile");

// iterate over the node list just like you would in jQuery with .each()
deleteButtons.forEach(function(button) {
  // do something with the individual element
  console.log(button);
});
```

Comment: This logic does not implement delegate practices.

Comment: Lots of folks have answered with event delegation, but it seems like the OP was primarily trying to figure out how to target all of the buttons like you can easily do in jQuery. That's why I focused my answer on that aspect of his question to keep things clear.

If you'd like to propose an edit to my answer that also covers the delegation issue go for it.

Comment: They are trying to convert their jQuery `on()`, which is in a delegate form, to a non-jQuery version.  I don't see where it says they do not want to use delegates anymore.  And their entire misunderstanding about why their logic will not work when they try to select the non-existing elements is entirely related to why the delegate was being used in the first place.

Comment: @JoSchMO While you are right about the OP missing the `querySelectorAll` function, your answer would have been better off as a side note to Taplar's answer, which already did mention `querySelectorAll`.

Comment: @MrLister yeah that would have been the way to go, but we all answered more or less simultaneously, it was a new question. 

I still believe the OP didn't realize event delegation was even at play, and was really asking something like "I'm trying to get away from depending on jQuery, how do I select all of these buttons?" So rather than edit my answer to include event delegation I wanted to provide an answer that would teach the OP how to accomplish that task.